# client and server are on localhost and yest I get: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes

Tags: http, angular, localhost, cross-domain

I wrote a client-side in an existing server-side project.

I ran both on localhost

How come I get `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes` error?

server:

```
localhost:8880/SupporTool/Push/SelectMessagesAttributes.
```

client:

```
http://localhost:63342/SupporTool/SupporTool_main/webapp/html/angular2/index.html?_ijt=5qo5v38f4p20oac99ca4jcgdi0
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different port is already treated as different domain. Either you serve on the same port or you configure the server to send CORS headers for client requests.

Comment: still happens even thought same host and port http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019403/client-from-localhost8880-calls-server-from-localhost8880-but-gets-cross-origi