# client from localhost:8880 calls server from localhost:8880 but gets Cross origin requests are only supported

Tags: http, angular, cross-domain

I have an html page with angular2 on url:

`http://localhost:8880/SupporTool/html/angular2/index.html#`

which call server on

`localhost:8880/SupporTool/Push/SelectMessagesAttributes`

how come i get

`Cross origin requests are only supported..`

[image]

Comment: Where does the port `63342` com from?. What's the full error message?

Comment: had wrong image. now uploaded the new problem. same host and port but yet same error

Comment: add `http://` on top of your URL

Comment: it's emitted anyway in the call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one has to disable same origin policy in Chrome. It blocks all calls from localhost to itself.

start chrome with the `--disable-web-security` flag

Comment: Do you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin ?